# How can I cause the name of views and partial views to be rendered with the rest of the markup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to, especially in a debug build config for example, like to have views and partial views emit their file names into the mark-up that they render. Is there some easily available view property I can use? Or would I have to override something like the View method in a derived controller to push this data into the view as it's being rendered?

*Aside: At present I derive all my view models from* `ViewModelBase`*, so this may be one vector of getting this information to the rendered HTML, but I don't know where to start.*

EDIT: James's answer below is perfect in telling me where to get the information, and how to render it, but I would appreciate some suggestions on how to incorporate this information in all views and partials. I realize I will probably have to resort to some low level framework coding, such as adding an overload of RenderPartial that renders a container element that I can tag the view name onto, such as in my first pass solution of doing the following in my master layout and views:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<section id="main" data-viewname="@(ViewBag.BodyViewName)">
    @RenderBody()
</section>
```

*[AllViews]*.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.BodyViewName = this.VirtualPath;
    ViewBag.Title = "My Courses";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `VirtualPath` property that is a member of the WebPageBase class that represents a razor page.  Inside of your view or partial view you can access this class and display its property like so:

```
@Html.Raw(this.VirtualPath)
```

**Edit:**

For the aspx view engine you can use this:

```
<% this.AppRelativeVirtualPath %>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I can add a `data-viewname` attribute to all my views and partials. Helps when debugging between browser and IDE. Any suggestions on how I could implement this?